# Usar la función print() dentro de un bucle For

Tags: python, funciones, bucle-for

tengo una función para eliminar una línea especifica de un archivo .txt en Python3.8 . El problema me surge al querer imprimir un mensaje por pantalla dependiendo de si la acción que se realiza es una u otra, entiendo que en un bucle FOR el comando print() se ejecutara tantas veces como iteraciones tenga la acción. Mi pregunta es: hay alguna manera para que el mensaje solo se muestre 1 vez al realizar la acción?

código:

```
def elimina_telefono(self, fichero, persona):
    self.fichero = 'agenda.txt'
    with open(fichero, 'r+') as archivo:
        nuevo_archivo = archivo.readlines()
        archivo.seek(0)
        for line in nuevo_archivo:
            if persona not in line.split('\n'):
                archivo.write(line)
            archivo.truncate()
            if persona in line.split('\n'):
                print('Contacto Borrado')
            elif persona not in line.split('\n'):
                print('Contacto no Encontrado')
```

resultado:

Contacto Borrado #  el 'nombre' estaba en la línea

Contacto no encontrado  #  el 'nombre' no esta en la línea

Contacto no encontrado  #   "
Contacto no encontrado  #   "

Comment: Ese código 1) borra el contenido del archivo de entrada y 2) graba de vuelta las líneas en donde **no** aparece la persona. El mismo archivo puede tener ambos tipos de lineas (aparece/no aparece la persona) y entonces debería imprimir una vez cada mensaje ("Contacto borrado", "Contacto no encontrado"). ¿Interprete bien la lógica?

Comment: ¿Quizás la idea es que, una vez que ha procesado todas las líneas del fichero imprima el mensaje "Contacto borrado" si es que lo encontró (y borró) en alguna de esas líneas, o bien el mensaje "Contacto no encontrado" si no lo encontró en ninguna de las líneas? En este segundo caso deberías tener una variable booleana `encontrado=False` antes de entrar al bucle, que harías `True` cuando detectas el contacto a borrar. Al salir del bucle harías un `if encontrado: ...` De ese modo el print estará fuera del `for` y se hará una sola vez.

Comment: @abulafia En una linea estará, en la otra no estará ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu pregunta admite dos intepretaciones:

- Una es que debas imprimir "Contacto Borrado" si *al menos una línea* contiene el contacto, y "Contacto no encontrado" si *al menos una línea* NO contiene al contacto. La solución a este caso es la respuesta de @CandidMoe. Entiendo que ya que el fichero contendrá probablemente líneas que contienen el contacto y líneas que no, este enfoque producirá al final ambos mensajes.
- Otra (que para mi tendría más sentido) es que debes imprimir "Contacto borrado" si al menos una línea contiene el contacto y "Contacto no encontrado" solo si **ninguna** línea contenía a ese contacto.

Para este segundo caso tendrías una sola variable booleana que al final del bucle deberá valer `True` si encontraste al contacto en *alguna* línea o `False` si no lo encontraste *en ninguna*. Para ello basta inicializarla con `False` antes de entrar al bucle, y ponerla a `True` cada vez que encuentres un contacto (no importa si aparece varias veces, pues seguirá siendo `True`). Si al salir del bucle aún es `False` es que no se encontró.

Por tanto el esquema general sería el siguiente (he movido también el `.truncate()` fuera del bucle pues basta hacerlo una sola vez y no en cada iteración, como menciona @CandidMoe):

```
def elimina_telefono(self, fichero, persona):
    with open(fichero, 'r+') as archivo:
        lineas = archivo.readlines()
        archivo.seek(0)
        archivo.truncate()

        encontrado = False
        for linea in lineas:
            if persona in linea:
                # Esta linea no se copia, pero tomamos nota de que se ha encontrado
                encontrado = True
            else:
                archivo.write(linea)

    if encontrado:
        print('Contacto Borrado')
    else:
        print('Contacto no Encontrado')
```

Comment: La interpretación correcta es la segunda! y la solución ofrecida para ello es la perfecta. Muchas gracias @abulafia por la ayuda ofrecida!!! y al resto de gente del post que a invertido un momento de su tiempo en esclarecer las dudas. Gracias a todos

Answer (score 0):

Si sólo quieres hacer algo una vez, agrega una condición y procede a la acción cuando hayas terminado el ciclo:

```
def elimina_telefono(self, fichero, persona):
    self.fichero = 'agenda.txt'
    with open(fichero, 'r+') as archivo:
        nuevo_archivo = archivo.readlines()
        archivo.seek(0)
        borrados = False
        no_encontrado = False
        for line in nuevo_archivo:
            if persona not in line.split('\n'):
                archivo.write(line)
            archivo.truncate()
            if persona in line.split('\n'):
                borrados = True
            elif persona not in line.split('\n'):
                no_encontrado = True

        if borrados:
            print('Contacto Borrado')
        if no_encontrado:
            print('Contacto no Encontrado')
```

Nota: El código se puede reducir sin cambiar su semántica.

No necesitas hacer `line.split("\n")` para revisar si `persona` está o no en la línea; basta con

```
if persona in line:
```

Tampoco necesitas preguntar una y otra vez lo mismo; una persona está o no está en la misma línea. Con una pregunta basta.

Dado que vas a aplicar `truncate()` si el archivo no está vacío, no necesitas hacerlo una y otra vez dentro del ciclo; puedes hacerlo al principio. Sin importar como llames a la función, siempre lo vas a truncar, tenga o no información.

No tiene sentido la asignación de una constante a `self.fichero`; eso se hace en el `__init__` de la clase. Aquí es completamente innecesario.

```
def elimina_telefono(self, fichero, persona):
    with open(fichero, 'r+') as archivo:
        nuevo_archivo = archivo.readlines()
        archivo.seek(0)
        archivo.truncate()
        borrados = False
        no_encontrado = False
        for line in nuevo_archivo:
            if persona not in line:
                no_encontrado = True
                archivo.write(line)
            else:
                borrados = True

        if borrados:
            print('Contacto Borrado')
        if no_encontrado:
            print('Contacto no Encontrado')
```

**Demo**

*test.txt*

```
juan soto, 9 4545 4444
jose perez, 9 1234 1234
rosa sanchez, 9 0999 2334
```

*Código*

Converti el método de clase a una simple función para la prueba:

```
elimina_telefono("test.txt", "juan")
```

*Resultado*

```
Contacto Borrado
Contacto no Encontrado
```

text.txt

```
jose perez, 9 1234 1234
rosa sanchez, 9 0999 2334
```

Comment: Muy buena explicación! sobre todo para alguien con conocimientos básicos! muchas gracias!!